# MIME type of mp3 file using Speech to Text

Tags: node.js, speech-to-text, ibm-watson, watson

I am using speech to text API of Watson. Initially I used a .wav file but I want to use a mp3 file. So I want know the MIME type of mp3 file for specifying the content type?

Comment: Hi, try to see my edit if you want to know about the new release for Speech to Text.

Comment: Thank you. Will let you know on any doubts :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see within [official documentation](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/speech-to-text/index.html) the Audio formats support is:

- **Audio formats:** Transcribes Free Lossless Audio Codec (*FLAC*), Linear 16-bit Pulse-Code Modulation (*PCM*), Waveform Audio File Format (*WAV*), Ogg format with the Opus or Vorbis codec, Web Media (*WebM*) format with the Opus or Vorbis codec, mu-law (or u-law) audio data, or basic audio.

Check: [MIME Types](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/speech-to-text/input.html#formats) for Speech to Text.

One good idea to use your mp3 audio is to convert before sending for the API.

And, depends on what you want, you can use [this](https://jrklein.com/2015/08/17/asterisk-voicemail-transcription-via-ibm-bluemix-speech-to-text-api/) article. In this article, Jason shows how to use mp3 with Asterisk to send the voice audio for Speech to Text. I'm not sure if works yet.

**EDIT:** [10/2017]

A few days ago, Watson Speech to Text release one new version that supports **mp3** input features.

**Check the audio formats supported now:**

**Audio formats:** Transcribe Free Lossless Audio Codec (FLAC), *MP3 (Motion Picture Experts Group, or MPEG) format*, Linear 16-bit Pulse-Code Modulation (PCM), Waveform Audio File Format (WAV), Ogg format with the Opus or Vorbis codec, Web Media (WebM) format with the Opus or Vorbis codec, mu-law (or u-law) audio data, and basic audio.

- See the [Official documentation](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/speech-to-text/index.html#inputFeatures) talking about here.